# Git blame history stats

Tags: git, bash

As `git blame` can be used to show what revision and author last modified each line of a file, it can be used to output statistic of how many LOC are currently in the repository originating from each committer:

```
$ git ls-tree --name-only -z -r HEAD | \
  egrep -z -Z -E "\\.(cc|h|cpp|hpp|c|cs|R|r|py|tex)$" | \
  xargs -0 -n1 git blame --line-porcelain | \
  grep "^author " | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Although `git log --numstat` provides an easy way to create time series showing the number of commits by author, or the LOC added by author, or the LOC deleted by author, etc., I don't see an easy way to create a time series showing the evolution of the actual number of LOC originating from each commiter.

I know I could just iterate over all the commits in the repo (or just some if detail/accuracy is not important) and execute the command above to let `git blame` recalculate the sum by author for each commit, but that does not seem to be efficient at all.

In order to create that time series in a more efficient way, one could very easily calculate the number of LOC added by author for each commit with `git log --numstat`, but then, instead of taking away the number of LOC deleted by the committer to the number of LOC of that committer, one would need to know, for each deleted line, who was the author (blame) and then, take off those lines to the number of LOC of that blamed author instead.

So I guess my question would be: is there a way to blame only the lines that were deleted in each commit?

Comment: with `-L` you can specify a range of the file to be used. You can do it regularly, store the last commit to recompute only from the last commit instead of all the history